# Xpath with text() contains and not contains other text, case insensitive

Tags: xpath, contains, translate

I am trying to locate an element based on its text (I know, I know), and because there are two labels that contain some of the same words, I have to be able to locate it by some words but ensure it doesn't include other words.  On top of that, it needs to be case insensitive.

Example: I am trying to locate and click the checkbox associated with the text Some Text, but not Some Text Too.  The id and name, as well as the order (sometimes 'Some Text' is first, sometimes 'Some Text Too' is first) can vary from page to page depending on what else is shown, so I cannot rely on that to locate the correct checkbox.

```
<td style="padding-bottom: 2px"><input id="c_58" style="padding-left: 3px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);" name="c_58" value="[dbo].[table].[Field]" type="checkbox"><label for="c_59" style="padding-left: 3px;">Some Text Too</label></td>

<td style="padding-bottom: 2px"><input id="c_59" style="padding-left: 3px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);" name="c_59" value="[dbo].[table].[Field]" type="checkbox"><label for="c_59" style="padding-left: 3px;">Some Text</label></td>
```

What I have that works:
    `//*[*[text()[contains(translate(., 'SOME TEXT','some text'), 'some text')]]]`

This finds the elements with `'Some Text'`, but also finds the elements with `'Some Text Too'`. Since sometimes the page renders with the elements in different order, I need to be able to ensure I'm only finding `'Some Text'` and not `'Some Text Too'`

I have tried :
    `//*[*[text()[contains(translate(., 'SOME TEXT','some text'), 'some text') and not(contains(translate(., 'TOO', 'too'), 'too'))]]]`

but that is not locating any element on the page.

Comment: There is more to my path than that - so the extra level is necessary. I didn't include it because this element is my anchor so once I can find it, I can find what I need.  But just FYI, removing the extra square brackets doesn't change my results. Still not finding the element that doesn't have the additional text.

Comment: Do you mind editing your question by including a sample of the document you are working with and also the expected output you wish to capture?

Comment: I just tested `//*[text()[contains(translate(., 'SOME TEXT','some text'), 'some text') and not(contains(translate(., 'TOO', 'too'), 'too'))]]` with your html script on [`firepath`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firepath/) for Firefox and it's pointing to the text without "Too". There must be something else leading to the issue you're having then.

Answer (score 0):

Abdou you were correct - my scenario was more like:

```
label 1 : Some Text Here Too
label 2 : Some Texts Here
```

So the having the term "Some Text Here" couldn't find the second label because of the non-matching "Texts".  I resolved this scenario by using:

```
//*[*[text()[contains(translate(., 'SOME','some'), 'some') and contains(translate(., 'TEXT','text'), 'text') and contains(translate(., 'HERE','here'), 'here') and not(contains(translate(., 'TOO','too'), 'too'))]]]

//*[*[text()[contains(translate(., 'SOME','some'), 'some') and contains(translate(., 'TEXT','text'), 'text') and contains(translate(., 'HERE','here'), 'here') and contains(translate(., 'TOO','too'), 'too')]]]
```